# Infinitely many primes in second-order recurrence

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

I just wondered about the following question:

Suppose that we are given a homogeneous second-order recurrence relation, $x_{n+2}+ax_{n+1}+bx_n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Can we choose integers $a$, $b$, $x_0$ and $x_1$ in such a way that the resulting sequence $(x_n)$ will contain *infinitely many* primes?

Does anybody know anything about this? Or any ideas? I couldn't come up with much, having done some years of maths at uni.

Comment: Try $a=2, x_0=0, x_1=1$.  This gives $x_n=n(-1)^{n+1}$.   There's no $b$ in your expression.

Comment: Sorry, I've now added $b$. I could have definitely thought about the easy cases first... :D

Comment: What about non-trivial solutions?

Comment: In the nontrivial cases, $x_n$ grows exponentially, and no such sequence has ever been proved to have infinitely many primes. On the other hand, people have found relatively prime integers $x_0,x_1$ such that the sequence given by $x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}+x_n$ has *no* primes.